# Optimize Query, SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these two queries. I wonder if there is a way to make it better.
I have created a index for atividade_id and automacao_id, but nothing seemed to change.

There are around 500.000 rows in those tables, and it takes like 6 seconds to select.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

```
CREATE INDEX index_atividade_automacao
ON emailcampanha (atividade_id,automacao_id);


SELECT Count(*) AS y0_ 
FROM   emailcampanhaemailclique this_
   INNER JOIN emailcampanhaemail emailcampa1_
           ON this_.email_id = emailcampa1_.id
   INNER JOIN emailcampanha emailcampa3_
           ON emailcampa1_.id_emailcampanha = emailcampa3_.id
   INNER JOIN emailcampanhalink link2_ 
           ON this_.link_id = link2_.id 
  WHERE emailcampa3_.automacao_id = 3
   AND emailcampa3_.atividade_id = 7


SELECT Count(*) AS y0_ 
FROM   emailcampanha this_ 
   INNER JOIN emailcampanhaemail emails1_
           ON this_.id = emails1_.id_emailcampanha
   WHERE this_.automacao_id = 7
   AND this_.atividade_id = 1
```

Comment: Please add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output to the question.

Comment: Query tunning is almost an art and hard to do without knowing the schema and query plans. 6 second is really a bad time to count only 500k records. There are many factor to consider but you can also see if there are indexes in that join clauses. Note like many DBMS it don't auto create indexes for FKs

Comment: @jean I disagree that it's almost an art.

Comment: Add indexes on id, emailcampa1_.id, etc and id_emailcampanha in their respective files and test it out.